# Access maven property in jsp/html file

Tags: javascript, html, maven, jsp, pom.xml

How can I access properties from pom.xml in html/jsp files?

I have properties in pom.xml file as follows:

```
<properties>
        <myProject.name>TestProject</myProject.name>
</properties>
```

In index.html, I want this myProject.name in href attribute of link tag like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${myProject.name}/resources/css/test.css"/>
```

I cannot modify pom.xml. How can I achieve this?

Comment: if you can access the pom you could enabling filtering on your html resources, ( however i would not do that ). Rather filter another file and use that in your code to inject data you want in your html/jsp.  https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Comment: Would `project.name` contain an arbitrary value, or will it be always the same as the context name?

Comment: Arbitrary value